# Background job on heroku how does the web know it's finished

Tags: javascript, ajax, heroku, sinatra, resque

So, I'm creating this application that sometime it require pulling the feed and it's always timeout on heroku because of the xml parser takes time. So, I change to be asynchronous load via Ajax every time the page is loaded. I still get H12 error from my Ajax call. Now I'm thinking of using Resque to run the job in background. I can do that no problem but how would I know that the job is finished so I can pull the processed feed on to the html page via AJAX?

Not sure if my question is clear, so how would the web layer knows that the job is done and it should signal e.g (onComplete in javascript) to populate the content on the page?

Comment: Not specific to Heroku, but you might be interested in a writeup I made on [using DRb as a server for long-running web processes](http://phrogz.net/drb-server-for-long-running-web-processes). It shows how to use AJAX to poll and return results from a process running in another thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this

- The JavaScript can use AJAX to poll the server asking for the results and the server can respond with 'not yet' or the results.  You keep asking until you get the results.
- You could take a look at Juggernaut (http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) which lets your server push to the client
- Web Sockets are the HTML5 way to deal with the problem.  There are a few gems around to get you started [Best Ruby on Rails WebSocket tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767268/best-ruby-on-rails-websocket-tool)

Answer (score 1):

You have an architecture problem here.  The reason for the H12 is so that the user is not sat there for more than 30 seconds.

By moving the long running task into a Resque queue, you are making it disconnected to the front end web process - there is no way that the two can communicate due to process isolation.

Therefore you need to look at what you are doing and how.  For instance, if you are pulling a feed, are you able to do this at some point before the user needs to see the output and cache the results in some way - or are you able to take the request for the feed from the user and then email them when you have the data for them to look at etc etc.

The problem you have here is that your users are asking for something which takes longer than a reasonable amount of time to complete, so therefore you need to have a good look at what you are doing and how.